# Finding rows that have the same foreign key and members of the set satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables, `user` and `user_set`. Both of these tables use the column `id` as their primary key.

`user` has the column `user_set_id` as a foreign key to indicate which user set it belongs to.

`user` table:

```
 id   | user_set_id  | name     | active | no_in_set         
------+--------------+----------+--------+------------
    1 |            1 | Alice    | t      | 3
    2 |            3 | Bob      | f      | 4
    3 |            2 | Charlie  | t      | 3
    4 |            2 | Daniel   | f      | 1
...
```

`user_set` table:

```
id   | name  
-----+--------
   1 | set1
   2 | set2
   3 | set3
...
```

One set always has exactly four users that belong to it. I would like to find user sets that satisfy the following conditions:

- user1 and user2 are active
- user3 and user4 are inactive

(User numbers are identified by the column `user.no_in_set`.)

For each of the sets that satisfy these conditions, I want to retrieve the name of user1.

Comment: I've corrected the typo in the example table, thank you.

Comment: By "active", do you mean "contained"? I would clarify what you're asking as something like: "I wish to find all sets that: A) contain both users 1 and users 2, B) do not contain users 3 and 4." Also confusing: "I want to retrieve the name of user1". Isn't user1 Alice? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking conditional aggregation:

```
select u.user_set_id
from user u
group by u.user_set_id
having bool_or( u.no_in_set = 1 and u.active) and
       bool_or( u.no_in_set = 2 and u.active) and
       bool_or( u.no_in_set = 3 and not u.active) and
       bool_or( u.no_in_set = 4 and not u.active) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of the fact that sets that satisfy all the conditions will have exactly 4 rows:

```
SELECT user_set_id, name
FROM user
WHERE no_in_set = 1 
    AND user_set_id IN (
        SELECT user_set_id 
        FROM user
        WHERE (no_in_set = 1 AND active) 
            OR (no_in_set = 2 AND active) 
            OR (no_in_set = 3 AND NOT active) 
            OR (no_in_set = 4 AND NOT active) 
        GROUP BY user_set_id 
        HAVING count(*) = 4)
ORDER BY user_set_id
```